# javascript does not work for margin-top

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some problems with this javascript, which should change the margin-top of one element when scrolling. But it doesnt work and I dont know why, because im never workes with javascript.

html and css are only the important parts.

HTML:

```
<link href=\"css2/bootstrap.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">
<link href=\"css2/bootstrap-responsive.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">
<link href=\"css2/font-awesome.min.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">
<link href=\"css2/colors.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">
<link href=\"css2/style.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">

<script>
$(window).scroll(function(){
var fromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
$(".widget").css('margin-top', '-' + (1000 - fromTop) + 'px');
});
</script>

<div class=\"search-form widget\">
...
</div>
```

style.css:

```
.widget {
}

.search-form {
padding: 30px 40px 10px;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
background: #fff; /* ie8 */
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.85);
border: 1px solid #fff;
position: fixed;
width: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Try this $(".widget").css('margin-top', '-' + (1000 - fromTop) + 'px !important'); If this does not work, then try $(".widget").css({'margin-top' : '-' + (1000 - fromTop) + 'px !important','float':'left'});

Comment: Thanks for your help but it still doesnt work. I believe its an beginners failure. Maybe the .css or $(window).scroll(function(){ is wrong.

Comment: Ok,It would be better if you could create a fiddle, so can test the issue in detail.

Comment: Ok, here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fo2uou7b/3/
doesnt work in fiddle too

Comment: update: it works in fiddle, just forgot to import, but not in my file, hmm maybe I imported something wrong

Comment: ok thanks ive got it, but now i have a bigger problem. The div element of the class search-form widget is a form. And with ja javascript for changing the margin-top i cant use ist. i cant klick in the forms and event cant press the submit button. why?